# Lifetime of a temporary captured by reference in a closure stored in a class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, lifetime, temporary-objects

Consider the following code snippet:

```
struct foo { };

template <typename F>
struct impl : F
{
    impl(F&& f) : F{std::move(f)} { }
    auto get() { return (*this)(); }
};

template <typename X>
auto returner(X&& x)
{
    return impl{[&x]{ return x; }};
//               ^~
}

int main()
{
    auto x = returner(foo{}).get();
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GSgIsLHXpuv4ztna)

---

- Is it guaranteed that `foo{}` will be alive for the entire duration of the `returner(foo{}).get()` expression?
- Or is `foo{}` going to be alive only for `returner(foo{})`, thus causing *undefined behavior* when invoking `impl::get()`?

---

The Standard says in [[class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#:constructor,copy):

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the *full-expression* that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

In [[intro.execution]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#def:full-expression)

> A full-expression is
>
> - an unevaluated operand,
> - a constant-expression,
> - an init-declarator or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
> - an invocation of a destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object other than a temporary object ([class.temporary]), or
> - an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and
>     that is not otherwise part of a full-expression.

I am not sure whether or not the *full-expression* related to `foo{}` is `returner(foo{})` or `returner(foo{}).get()`.

Comment: Am I getting this right? You inherit impl from a lambda. In impl's constructor you call the base class's constructor, the base class being a lambda?

Comment: @Zebrafish: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important section here is that:

> A *full-expression* is [...] an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a *full-expression*.

So in `returner(foo{}).get()`, `returner(foo{})` is a subexpression of the expression `returner(foo{}).get()`, so it's not a full-expression. Hence:

> Is it guaranteed that `foo{}` will be alive for the entire duration of the `returner(foo{}).get()` expression?

Yes.

Comment: The shorthand 99% accurate rule of thumb is "full exoressions end at `;`, or where there could be a `;` and leave semantics unchanged"

Comment: Well, the actual full-expression here is the *init-declarator* :)